# Array with less values than length - null-overhead in json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I'm writing a simple game. It's based on a field that is 32x32 squares. Each square can contain a game element. When an element appears/moves/changes, the server sends a json object containing a 2d array that resembles the whole game field with all it's elements via websockets to all clients.

That is quite a lot of data when sent to multiple clients, multiple times per second.

So I was wondering how I could reduce that.

I thought it would help to remove everything from the big array that the client already received anyways. But if you have something like this:

```
var gameField = [];
gameField[6][10] = "player1";
console.log(JSON.stringify(gameField));
```

it converts to:

```
[null,null,null,null,null,null,[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"player1"]]
```

That's really unnecessary overhead.

Couldn't it generate something like this instead?

```
{"6": {"10":"player1"}}
```

I'm using node.js for the game server btw.

So how do I reduce the data? Is there maybe a special JSON.stringify method?

Comment: It could have if you used a plain object, not an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an object instead of an array.

```js
var gameField = {};

gameField[6] = gameField[6] || {};

gameField[6][10] = "player1";

console.log(JSON.stringify(gameField));
```

Comment: But I already have my server side completely based on the array structure. So I have to convert it when it is being sent to the client. How could that be done?

Comment: @Forivin this is a separate question, isn't it?

Comment: It was meant to be the original one.

Comment: @Forivin: see [Converting an Array-like Object (List) to an Array](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/187/arrays/2333/converting-an-array-like-object-list-to-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the json parsing, by using a replacer function. However the parsing `reviver` would depend on how the inner objects are recognized. For example, if the inner objects are strings as in the example:

```js
var gameField = [];
gameField[6] = [];
gameField[6][10] = "player1";

function replacer(key,val){
 if(val instanceof Array){
    return val.reduce((o,el,i)=>{
       if(el)o[i] = el;
       return o;
      },{});
  }
  return val;
}

var json = JSON.stringify(gameField, replacer);
console.log("JSON: ", json);

function reviver(key,val){
 if(typeof val === 'string')
     return val;
  return Object.keys(val).reduce((arr,k) =>{
   arr[k] = val[k];
    return arr;
  }, [] );
}

gameField = JSON.parse(json, reviver);
console.log("Parsed: ", gameField);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove **null** from the array, use underscore library.

`npm install underscore --save`

in your file where the related code is there,

```
var _ = require('underscore');
```

To remove null just pass

```
result = _.filter(result, function(item){
            return item!= null;
        });
```

`result` will be an array without any null.

Comment: That would break the parser, as it wouldn't be valid json anymore.

Comment: But why Underscore? [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is available in all reasonably relevant Node versions.

Comment: @Forivin the solution i suggested was for getting rid of null from the array.

Comment: @Pavlo underscore library provides a lot of easy to execute functionality over arrays in js, thatswhy i prefer it.