# Convert object to multidimensinal array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, multidimensional-array

I basically want to do this in reverse: [Convert multidimensional array to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567371/convert-multidimensional-array-to-object/38567533?noredirect=1#comment64525173_38567533)

So let's say I have an object like this:

```
{
  "6": {"10":{'id':0,'name':'player1'}},
  "7": {"5":{'id':1,'name':'player2'}}
}
```

How can I convert that into a legit array like this:

```
[
    null, 
    null, 
    null, 
    null, 
    null, 
    null, 
    [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, {'id':0,'name':'player1'}],
    [null, null, null, null, null, {'id':1,'name':'player2'}]
]
```

This is the code that I successfully used to convert it the other way around:

```
function populateFromArray(array) {
  var output = {};
  array.forEach(function(item, index) {
    if (!item) return;
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
      output[index] = populateFromArray(item);
    } else {
      output[index] = item;
    }
  });
  return output;
}

console.log(populateFromArray(input));
```

Comment: Numbers as attribute names isn't generally a greatest idea.

Comment: Technically, it already is a legitimate array. `obj[7][5]` returns `{id: 1, name: "player2"}`. The only difference, I guess, is that instead of `null` all unregistered array positions are `undefined`.

Comment: Well I want to loop through the thing without getting errors or checking for undefined. Atm obj[0][0] would through an error, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Forivin: Yes, because `obj[0]` is `undefined`, so it has no first element.

Comment: `obj[0][0]` would also throw an error with your new structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function objectToArray(obj) {
  var len = Math.max.apply(null, Object.keys(obj));
  if (len !== len) return obj; // checking if NaN

  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
    output[i] = null;
    if (obj[i]) { 
      output[i] = objectToArray(obj[i]);
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = {
  "6": {"10":{'id':0,'name':'player1'}},
  "7": {"5":{'id':1,'name':'player2'}}
};

function populateArray(obj) {
  var range = 0,
      arr = [];

  for (var index in obj) {
    range = Math.max(parseInt(index), range);   
  }

  for (var i = 0; i <= range; i++) {
    if (obj[i+'']) {
      arr[i] = populateArray(obj[i+'']);
    } else {
      arr[i] = null;
    }
  }

  return arr;
}

console.log(populateArray(obj))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38566723/array-with-less-values-than-length-null-overhead-in-json), assuming the source is json, you can use a revive function as well to convert the data directly when parsing

```js
var json = '{ "6": {"10":{"id":0, "name":"player1"}}, "7": {"5":{"id":1,"name":"player2"}}}';

function reviver(key,val){ 
 if(isNaN(key) || val.id !== undefined)
     return val;
  var res = [];
  for(var p in val)
      res[p] = val[p];
   return res;
}

var gameField = JSON.parse(json, reviver);
console.log(gameField);
```